# Object doesn't update when I save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am probably missing something obvious, but when I try to save an object, it doesn't update in the database.  I can insert objects.  Here are my models.  I can do everything correctly on the User model, I am just having issues with the dispute model.

```
class Dispute < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :reason
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email
  has_many :disputes
end
```

I then try to...

```
d = Dispute.new
d.save  # This works, it is inserted correctly
  BEGIN
  INSERT
  COMMIT
d.reason = "This is a reason"
d.save  # This doesn't work
  BEGIN
  COMMIT
d.reason = "This is a different reason"
d.changed?
  true
d.save
  BEGIN
  COMMIT
```

Not sure what I am missing.  I did simplify it a bit.  I have numerous other objects in this project, and they all work just fine.

```
d.update_attributes( :reason => "This is a reason" )
```

This also behaves the same way, where it doesn't update the record in the database, yet it returns true.

Comment: And `.save` returns true too?

Comment: After `d.reason = "This is a reason"` and `d.save`, can you find the record by doing Dispute.find_by_reason('This is a reason')?

Comment: @Dogbert - Yes, it does return true.

Comment: @garbagecollection when I do the search, I get nil back, which makes sense because it isn't being updated in the database.

Comment: Just a cheap shot: did you try using a different name for the active record (Dispute) or the attribute (reason), just in case it's in conflict with an obscure gem or something?

Comment: @Karl, what happens with `Dispute.new(reason: "...").save!`?

Comment: This sounds like you can't save because there's some validator you haven't showed us that's failing the save method. `save!` should tells you which validation is failing the method

Comment: save! returns true as well.

Comment: @Karl Do you actually have a `reason` field in your table?

Comment: @meagar - It is in the table.

Comment: @Dogbert That does work correctly, but if I try to do an update_attributes on the same dispute that I just created, it doesn't update in the database.

Comment: @mbratch thanks for the idea, but sadly I get the same issue, I can insert, but not update records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check `.valid?` to see if it fails because of validations?

Dispute belongs to User, which has many Disputes.
You should create Disputes in a way that they are always associated with a User account.

Can you try this:

```
 u = User.first
 d = Dispute.new
 d.user = u
 d.save
 d.reason = "something"
 d.save
 d.persisted?
 d.valid?
```

and then you can try it the other way around:

```
 u = User.first
 u.disputes.create(:reason => "something else")
 u.save
```

this should also work

Comment: if you create a dispute by itself, without being owned / associated with a user, and then save the dispute, I would expect it to fail because of validations.   Weird

Comment: Alright, I did what you asked.

    u = User.first
    d = Dispute.new
    d.user = u
    d.save      # Inserted correctly and is tied to the user
    d.reason = "Something"
    d.save!     # Says it saved correctly, but did not update the database
    d.persisted? # true
    d.valid?     # true

Comment: are you overriding something from ActiveRecord::Base by accident?

Comment: I am using mysql.  I don't think I am, but I will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: you had the solution, I was overriding the update method.  Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: glad it helped - that's a tough one to find.

Answer (score 0):

In general/future reference: You will be able to see the exact reason why the d.save fails if you look at the server logs on your Dev server. Just scroll back up in the console until you see the attempted CRUD action that failed. The reason for failing should be stated there.

Can you post the output from the log if you're still having trouble w/ this?